# Jquery blur function not working for bootstrap modal

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-modal

I am trying for a blur function and show but show not working.It is hided when document.ready

```
$(function() {
  $("#chargeFee").blur(function(){
    if($("#chargeFee").val()>0) {
      alert($("#pay2").show());
      $("#pay").show();
    }
  });
```

pay id element is not showing....I am doing it on bootstrap popup.pay id element is hided when document is ready.

Comment: It is a bootstrap modal? if it is...$('#pay').modal('show');

Comment: Why are you using alert($("#pay2").show());

Comment: Works fine for me: https://jsfiddle.net/w4eLhwnh/

Comment: acutally I am using jquery steps for modal and pill should be added dynamically based on chargeFee value.But the pill is not showing when the value is above zero

Comment: @Roy It is working with what you have given

Comment: Nice!, good coding my friend!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 $("#pay").hide()
$("#chargeFee").blur(function(){
if(parseInt($("#chargeFee").val())>0){
        $("#pay").show();
}
 else
 {
   $("#pay").hide();
 }
});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="chargeFee">
<p id="pay">Pay</p>
```

Comment: acutally I am using jquery steps for modal and pill should be added dynamically based on chargeFee value.But the pill is not showing when the value is above zero

Answer (score 0):

You are calling the modal incorrectly.

The syntax for your modal calls would be.

```
$("#pay2").modal("show");
```

Another issue is you are trying to call a modal within an alert function in your line of code. This just will not work.

```
alert($("#pay2").show());
```

Comment: acutally I am using jquery steps for modal and pill should be added dynamically based on chargeFee value.But the pill is not showing when the value is above zero